# How can I toggle Automatic Graphics Switching using terminal?

Tags: gpu

I have a 15" MacBook Pro from May 2019 with a Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB graphics card. I would like to change the `Automatic Graphics Switching` setting with a terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some googling, and I do not know of a *native command line utility*, or a third-party *command line utility*, that can toggle the state of automatic graphics switching; however it can be done from the *command line* by utilizing **AppleScript** to toggle the **[√] Automatic graphics switching** *checkbox* on the **Energy Saver** *pane* in **System Preferences**.

In lieu of finding a *native command line utility*, or a third-party *command line utility*, or until a better answer is posted, the following will allow you to toggle it from the *command line* in e.g. **Terminal**.

1. In **Terminal**, use the following *compound command* to create the **file** and open it:

   ```
   touch togags; open togags
   ```
2. Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, into the opened `togags` **file**.
3. Save and close the **file**.
4. Make the **file** *executable*:

   ```
   chmod u+x togags
   ```

I used `togags` for: `[tog]gle [a]utomatic [g]raphics [s]witching`

You can now use it from the *directory* it's in using `./togags` otherwise `/path/to/togags`; however, it's best if you place in into a *directory* that's within your `PATH` *statement*. Then it can be used from anywhere by just `togags`, (or whatever you actually named the *executable*).

**NOTE:** This will also require giving **Terminal** [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) for this to work properly.

Running the *command* twice, to show its output:

```
$ togags
   Automatic Graphics Switching is: OFF
$ togags
   Automatic Graphics Switching is: ON
$
```

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, was tested and works me as coded on **macOS High Sierra**. A minor change *may* be needed for **macOS Mojave**; however, I'm not able to test at the present time. The same goes for older versions of OS X/macOS.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        quit application "System Preferences"
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.energysaver"
    repeat until exists window "Energy Saver"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell ¬ 
    group 1 of window "Energy Saver" of application process "System Preferences"
    repeat until exists checkbox "Automatic graphics switching"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Automatic graphics switching"
    set cbAGS to (value of checkbox "Automatic graphics switching") as boolean
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"

if cbAGS then
    return "   Automatic Graphics Switching is: ON"
else
    return "   Automatic Graphics Switching is: OFF"
end if
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and other then what's already coded, it does not contain any additional error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: I put it into the `/usr/local/bin` directory and it works great!

Comment: @Dev, Please do not waste your time attempting to edit my answers in the manner you've tried to do this one, I will just reject your edits such as this every time!

Answer (score 10):

The command `sudo pmset -a gpuswitch n` will set the graphics switching, with the following values for n:

- 2 is integrated gpu both on cable and battery
- 1 is dedicated gpu only with power connected; integrated gpu on battery power
- 0 is dedicated gpu on both ac and battery

`pmset -g` will show you the current configuration.

Comment: For me, running Catalina on a 2019 macbook pro 16", value 2 is AMD Radeon Pro on both cable and battery, 0 is Intel UHD Graphics on both cable and battery somehow reversed

Comment: The value 1 is acting weird, not sure what it is doing, seems to alternate between the graphics card randomly

Comment: It seems like 1 is true automatic graphics switching determined by the OS I think but it doesn't follow the power source. I used https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202053 to figure out which graphics card it is using

Comment: @Pencilcheck I'm running Catalina in 2019 macbook pro 16,oncable, when "automatic switching" checked, 2 and 0 both use the intergrated crad, and 1 will uncheck the "automatic switching" and using dedicated card.

Answer (score 3):

I find this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8160651 but it not match my 2018 MacBook with macOS Mojave 10.14

```
0 = Does not use dedicated graphics
1 = Use dedicated graphics
2 = Switch automaticly is default value when "Automatic Graphics Switching" selected in energy in preference.
```

The `-a` `-b` `-c` `-u` flags determine whether the settings apply
to battery `-b` , charger (wall power) `-c` , UPS `-u` or all `-a`

Check settings depended on charger/battery
`pmset -g custom`

Let system use dedicated graphics card when charger plugin
`sudo pmset -c gpuswitch 1`

Let system use graphics card auto switch when using battery
`sudo pmset -b gpuswitch 2`

Let system use auto switch on charger & battery `sudo pmset -a gpuswitch 2`

Answer (score 0):

Using this app: [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/), you can switch to the card you want.