# Can "Discrete only" GPU cause slowness?

Tags: performance, power, gpu, power-management

I have 2 external monitors to my 2017 Macbook Pro v.10.15.6. Sometimes it slows -- the mouse lags badly.

I installed gfxCardStatus and sometimes the menu choice changes from *Dynamic switching* to *Discrete only*. It seems that the mouse starts lagging just when that happens.

- Is it possible that "Discrete only" slows the computer?
- Why does this switch automatically?
- How can I keep it on "Dynamic switching"? The Macbook is always plugged in so power consumption is not a concern.

(This relates to [my earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394669/why-does-automatic-graphics-switching-keep-re-enabling-itself-without-my-involve), in which "Automatic graphics switching" under Energy saver was getting automatically enabled. I wrote a script to keep it disabled, for better performance with more power consumption. It seems that that is a different setting from this "Dynamic switching" in gfxCard Status since Dynamic switching seems to increase performance.)

[image: gfxStatus]

Comment: Presumably this is a 2017 MacBook Pro? The whole point of  Discrete GPUs is to offer better performance than the Integrated unit, so it *shouldn't* slow it down. However, discrete GPUs seem to be the cause of lots of problems.

Comment: Thank you, yes, 2017. I edited the text to clarify. What you say about performance makes sense. Is there a way to force my Mac to stay on "Dynamic Switching"?

Comment: The person to ask is the author of gfxcardstatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of gfxCardStatus [answered here](https://github.com/codykrieger/gfxCardStatus/issues/338#issuecomment-660780084).

> If your goal is better performance regardless of power consumption,
> then the solution is really simple: quit gfxCardStatus, delete it, and
> disable automatic graphics switching in System Preferences > Energy
> Saver. That will cause the discrete GPU to be used all the time.
>
> When gfxCardStatus is running, it manages the automatic graphics
> switching setting for you. Dynamic Switching is equivalent to having
> the automatic graphics switching checkbox checked.